# Adding time to calender using Event Kit

Tags: ios, xcode4

I need to add some events at a particular date and time using EventKit. For  example, I would like to add events on September 2, 2012, 1:00 pm.

If any one knows explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify a particular date, you should use date components:

```
NSCalendar *greg = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comps.day = 2;
comps.month = 9;
comps.year = 2012;
comps.hour = 13;

NSDate *eventDate = [greg dateFromComponents:comps];
```

To add an event via EventKit, use `eventWithEventStore:`and the modify the property `startDate`.